# What category should we nominate @Oli in the http://ubucon.de/node/921?

Tags: discussion

It's unclear to me in what category our local [god](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) should be nominated in the first [UbuContest](http://ubucon.de/node/921)...

As per the site:

3/ **Outstanding Technical Contribution:** Members of the general public may nominate candidates who, in their opinion, have done something "exceptional" with an Ubuntu-based device, Unity8, Mir, etc. on a technical level. Each jury member has one vote, and the nominated candidate with the most jury votes wins.

4/ **Outstanding Non-Technical Contribution:** Members of the general public may nominate candidates who, in their opinion, have done something exceptional, but non-technical, to bring the Ubuntu platform forward. So, for example, you can nominate a friend who has reported and commented on all those phone-related bugs on Launchpad. Or nominate a member of your local community who did translations for Core Apps. Or nominate someone who has contributed documentation, written awesome blog articles, etc. The rest of the rules are identical to the "Outstanding Technical Contribution" category.

My question is: *Should it be category 3 or 4 or both???*

Comment: I find it mildly amusing that the linked post is in English but the form and other links are in German.

Comment: @muru I find it even more amusing that when you answer "Ja / Yes" on the "Bist Du ein Mensch? (Bots: Nicht lügen!) / Are you human? (Bots: Do not lie!)" CAPTCHA question , it refuses it as a correct answer!

Comment: Hmmm. So we have another bot in our midst, eh? A post by Fabby, answer by known bot Rinzwind. Fishy. Very Fishy. :P

Comment: Category #3 would probably fit NathanOsman better...

Comment: @muru you are the most funniest bot I ever met.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A god transcends categories.

Oli would fit #4 more I would assume.

Comment: Oli's contributions, as far as I have seen, tend to emphasize the proper usage of Ubuntu rather than its inner technical workings. So, yes, category  4 is the better fit.